# How to read the next line in a text file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read the next new line in a text file and place it into an array, I was able to place the first line to an array. But I want to place each line in the text file into in separate arrays, is there a way to jump to the next line in the text file?

Code:

```
while(((ch = getc(file1))!= '\n') && (i < 30))
{
    day1_array[i] = ch;

    printf("%c",ch);


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i` doesn't change in your code

Comment: read about `fgets` function

Comment: [man getc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getc): *fgetc(), getc() and getchar() return the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error.*. That is, you can keep reading until `EOF`. And you can declare a 2D array for storing multiple lines. Also, unless you are required to use `getc` a better function instead would be `fgets` to read a whole line at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading text file into an array of lines in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800295/reading-text-file-into-an-array-of-lines-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
while (fgets(buf, MAX_LEN - 1, fp))
{
    printf("%s", buf);
}
```

where buf is some char array, MAX_LEN is the maximum expected line length and fp is the file pointer. The function fgets reads until either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end of file is reached. Must not be in this order, basically whichever come first

Comment: "expected line length" --> Would you consider `"123\n"` a line of length 3 or 4?  C lib has "each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character."

Comment: Using `sizeof buf` is less error prone than `MAX_LEN - 1`.  To read `"123\n"`, the array should be at least size 5.

Comment: I think you might be wrong on this one. Escape characters are not two bytes, just one. So to read your example, we just need four not five bytes, including the newline. Though I agree, sizeof(buf) might be a better option here, but still, in my opinion this answer satisfies the question asked. If you disagree, we can discuss about it and make modifications in order to make it better!

Comment: " to read your example, we just need four not five bytes" --> `fgets()` needs a buffer of at least 5 bytes to fully read and save the line made up of 4 keys `'1'`,  `'2'`,  `'3'`,  `'\n'`.  That is saved as a string with `'1'`,  `'2'`,  `'3'`,  `'\n'`,  `'\0'`.   Using `MAX_LEN - 1`  where `MAX_LEN` is the length of a line (4 in the above `"123\n"`), should be `MAX_LEN + 1` to provide the needed 5 and well as `buf[/* at least */ MAX_LEN+1]` is needed.